# Barrell files with eslint import/prefer-default-export

Tags: javascript, eslint

In some cases I prefer to have barrel files because it groups import in a logical way:

```
import {
    reducer1,
    reducer2,
    reducer3
} from './reducers'
```

I am working in a new project with an eslint file where `import/prefer-default-export` is enabled.

Can I still achieve the same effect as barbell files or should I not do that?

I tried:

```
export { default as reducer1 } from './reducer1';
```

but it felt like trying to force a square into a circle, and it also gave a `Prefer default expor` eslint error.

Comment: You may disable it for a one-off occurrence: 
// eslint:disable-next-line: ban-barrel-imports